# How can I use CAS in .NET 4 to lock down my MEF extensions?

Tags: .net-4.0, mef, code-access-security

I have an application in .NET 4 that uses MEF for extensibility.  My main application has three assemblies: `Host`, `Application` and `Contracts`.

`Host` is the "boot-strapping" executable that creates the container and does the composition.

`Application` contains the logic of my application, and more extension points for 3rd parties.

`Contracts` contains the interfaces (and some helper classes) that are used in the extension points.

Therefore, someone developing a 3rd party application has to include a reference to `Contracts`, but not to `Application`.

I'm thinking that my security model should look like this:

1. `Host` and `Application` should be **SecurityCritical**
2. `Contracts` should be **SecuritySafeCritical**
3. All 3rd party extensions should be **SecurityTransparent**

I think that 1. will be satisfied by default.  I know that I can implement 2. with an assembly attribute.  The question is, how do I enforce rule 3.?  Does the operating system do this automatically by flagging all downloaded extensions as untrusted?  Is it possible for a downloaded extension assembly to become fully trusted?

Comment: You ask: "Is it possible for a downloaded extension assembly to become fully trusted?"  This may depend on how extensions are getting downloaded. If a user can manually download an assembly, and then right-click-Properties on it and choose "Unblock", it looks to the system like a local assembly.

Comment: @JaredReisinger: That makes sense.  I guess 3rd parties can also sign assemblies, but I'm fuzzy about the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is running in full trust, then by default your extensions will be running in full trust and be able to do anything they want.  It won't matter what the security attributes on them are.  To limit what extensions can do, you need to create a sandbox appdomain.  You would set your `Host` and `Application` as fully trusted in that AppDomain and all other code would only have the permissions you grant it.

Here's an MSDN article on this topic: [How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx)

Comment: I'm thinking it's a lost cause.  Anyone who writes a 3rd party extension and packages it into an install file and gets the owner of the PC to execute the install file will be able to run their code in full trust.  MEF doesn't let you load extension assemblies into their own app domain.  Maybe it's possible for me to load my very critical code (containing security keys, etc.) into *its* own app domain.

Comment: @Scott You can design your app so that 3rd party extensions are a package that your app understands instead of executable install files.  Then you have your app manage the extensions and don't let it execute code on install.  MEF doesn't do anything specific with AppDomains, but you can still create a sandboxed AppDomain and then create a MEF container within that AppDomain.  Or you could look at System.Addin (MAF), which does handle creating plugins in different AppDomains.  MAF is quite complicated though, so it might be easier to roll your own sandboxing with MEF.